# Node.js for loop not leading to splice of all matching items

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I'm trying to splice all matching items of `parcel` in an array inside an object.

Example of array of objects called `documents`:

```
[
{name: "first", content: ["1", "2", "1", "3"]},
{name: "second", content: ["2", "1", "1", "1"]},
{name: "third", content: ["4", "1", "3", "2"]},
]
```

`parcel = 1` and I'm trying to splice all instances of `1`.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
console.log(parcel);
const parcel = 1;
console.log("doc start", documents);
for (i of documents) {
    // get index by count
    let count = -1;
    for (j of i.content) {
      count = count + 1;
      console.log(j);
      if (j == parcel) {
        i.content.splice(count, 1);
      }
    }
  }
console.log("doc end", documents);
```

Here's what the console logs with different array example:

```
parcel 1
doc start [
  {
    title: '1',
    content: [
      '1', '2', '2',
      '3', '1', '1',
      '2', '3'
    ]
  }
]
1
2
3
1
2
3
doc end [ { title: '1', content: [ '2', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3' ] } ]
```

You can see that `j` doesn't seem to be looping through the whole of `i.content`, which means that the `if` statement is not running to splice all the correct items.

The end result of the console log should be:

```
doc start [{title: '1', content: [ '2', '2', '3', '2', '3' ]}]
```

I'm not sure why this is happening...

Comment: Neither `i` or `j` are properly declared.  Should never write code this way.

Comment: could you please post an end result that you want to archieve?

Comment: ohh, interesting. Sorry I'm fairly new to this --the linter we use at work corrected my for loops to write like this. Can you share any source on why this isn't best practice and how it should be written?

Comment: well that linter seems to be messing up your code

Comment: No it was for work itself, and wouldn't let me merge because simple loops should be written like this. Still not seeing how it's causing an issue here though

Comment: Any reason you can't use `map` and `filter`? (And you should throw that linter out.)

Comment: Maybe I've looked at it too much and maybe I'm still too green for JS, but I couldn't get it map or filter to work for the content array in each object of the parent array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete multiple items from an Array you are iterating through you may get unexpected results, due to the way how `for-in`/`for-of` or `array.forEach()` works.

They all iterate through the array similar to a `for(;;)`-loop, where you just increase the index, no matter what.

They are all similar to:

```js
for (let idx = 0; idx < array.length; idx++) {
  // logic goes here
}
```

But if you delete the item at index 1 by using `array.splice()`, the item which was previously at index 2 becomes the item at index 1, all following items also reduce their index by one. Therefor the item which was previous index 2, will be skipped.

For more informations you can take a look at the [spec of the `for-of` statements](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements).

In this example, you can see, that the item at index 3 (value 4) is skipped.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let idx = 0;
for (const item of arr) {
    console.log(idx, item);
    if (item == 3) {
        arr.splice(idx,1);
    }
    idx++;
}
console.log(arr);
```

If you want to mutate the array, there are several ways which can be used.

- [Array.prototype.reduceRight(callback, initialValue)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)
- a for/while loop

  - that only increases the index if nothing was changed
  - reduces the index starting from the last one
- Use `Object.keys(obj).reverse()` or `Object.entries(obj).reverse()`

  ```js
  Object.entries(array).reverse().forEach(([idx, item]) => {
    /* splice logic goes here */
  })
  ```

***Note:*** `Array.prototype.filter` should only be used, if the reference to the array isn't stored anywhere else.

#### Examples:

Using a while or for loop, that only increases the index if nothing was deleted.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length;) {
  let item = arr[idx];
  console.log(idx, item);
  if (item == 3) {
     arr.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
     idx++;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Going backwards through the index numbers of the array.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

for (let idx = arr.length - 1; idx > -1; --idx) {
  let item = arr[idx];
  console.log(idx, item);
  if (item == 3) {
    arr.splice(idx, 1);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

With `array.reduceRight()`, which also starts at the highest item/index:

From the Docs:

> `initialValue`
>
> Value to use as accumulator to the first call of the callbackFn. **If no initial value is supplied, the last element in the array will be used and skipped.** Calling reduce or reduceRight on an empty array without an initial value creates a TypeError.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
// only if the array is not empty
// acc or return value is not needed
arr.length && arr.reduceRight((acc, item, idx) => {
    console.log(idx, item);
    if (item == 3) {
        arr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    // can be anything, but must be present
}, "unused Initial Value");
console.log(arr);
```

Based on your example using Object.entries():

```js
const array = [
  { name: "first", content: ["1", "2", "1", "3"] },
  { name: "second", content: ["2", "1", "1", "1"] },
  { name: "third", content: ["4", "1", "3", "2"] },
];

for (const { content } of array) {
  if (Array.isArray(content)) {
    Object.entries(content).reverse().forEach(([idx, item]) => {
      if (item === "1") {
        content.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might work. For each object in the iteration a new object is created using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and a new content array is created by filtering out all the `1`s from the existing array.

```js
const data=[{name:"first",content:["1","2","1","3"]},{name:"second",content:["2","1","1","1"]},{name:"third",content:["4","1","3","2"]}];

const out = data.map(obj => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    content: obj.content.filter(n => Number(n) !== 1)
  };
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: It does replace `content`. Only `map` returns a new array which is what you're seeing. Did you want to mutate the array instead?

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to filter by content you should use `map` and `filter` built in methods of arrays

```
const parcel = 1

const result = [
    {name: "first", content: ["1", "2", "1", "3"]},
    {name: "second", content: ["2", "1", "1", "1"]},
    {name: "third", content: ["4", "1", "3", "2"]},
    ].map(item =>({...item, content:item.content.filter(amount => Number(amount) !== parcel)}))
```